# Read xml file with more than one value in one tag in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have xml file like this

```
  <Sample_Data>
    <lastname Name="lastname" Value="FIRSTNAME" />
    <firstname Name="firstname" Value="LASTNAME" />
    <DM Name="DM" Value="93.2" />
    <CP Name="CP" Value="7.7" />
  </Sample_Data>
```

I need to read this file with java and I use code like this:

```
 try {

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse("File.xml");

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Sample_Data");

    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;


            System.out.println("First Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("DM : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("DM").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println("CP : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("CP").item(0).getTextContent());

        }
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I can't get values of firstname, lastname, DM and CP I get empty values for them.

Can someone help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your elements doesn't have a text node. So `getTextContent()` is empty. You should read the attributes instead.

`getElementsByTagName().item(0)` returns a `Node`, so you should first cast it to `Element`.

```
((Element) eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0)).getAttribute("Value")
```

In procuction code, you should also check, if the `NodeList`  `eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname")` contains some items.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best thing to do is to get a proper XML file. That way you would not have to parse multiple attributes.

You got that :

```
<Sample_Data>
    <lastname Name="lastname" Value="FIRSTNAME" />
    <firstname Name="firstname" Value="LASTNAME" />
    <DM Name="DM" Value="93.2" />
    <CP Name="CP" Value="7.7" />
</Sample_Data>
```

Instead you should have something like that :

```
<Sample_Data>
    <lastname> FIRSTNAME </lastname>
    <firstname> firstname </firstname>
    <DM> 93.2 <DM/>
    <CP> 7.7 </CP>
</Sample_Data>
```

Wouldn't that be easier to work with ?

Comment: Yes that would be easier but I get xml file like in my example. Thanks for your comment.